# Screen and print layout for a XAML window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have a rather complex WPF XAML window, which represents a printed form.

Mainly, on top, there is a **Canvas at size of an A4 page**. The children of the canvas are a lot of nested StackPanels, and then again lots of labels, textblocks, textboxes, labels, check boxes, drop downs, etc.

I print the window as follows:

```
PrintDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    dlg.PrintVisual(this.PageCanvas, "Document");
}
```

Now, during print, I want that colors and borders of textboxes disappear. Even more, I'd even like to replace some **TEXTBOXES** and **CHECKBOXES** with **TEXTBLOCKS**.

**a)** Are there pre-built methods for switching between "screen mode" and "print mode"?

**b)** Or, otherwise, can I exchange certain controls at run time with textblocks ?

I want to avoid to create two variants of the same form (one for screen, one for print), because this would double all future maintenance work.

Comment: I think that in order to achieve the requested behavior you would like to create a template for printing and upon print the template will change you current view for "print mode". In that way you can change the controls to whatever behavior you would like. Have a look here for an idea how to perform it: http://www.nullskull.com/a/1378/wpf-printing-and-print-preview.aspx , let me know if that works for you and I'll post it as answer for others too

Comment: @DeJaVo thanks, that looks like a promising article. Will need some time to go through that all and try it with my project - I will then post here again.

Comment: I'll wait for you update if that works for you I'll share an answer

Comment: @DeJaVo Well, the article you sent is mainly about pagination. However, it was useful for something else, as I posted another question some days ago. Now for this: I found a way to replace a control at runtime like this: `this.somepanel.Children.Remove(this.sometextbox); TextBlock n=new TextBlock(); this.somepanel.Children.Add(n); ` This is now just for a 1st version, as I want to get out something working. Then, I will take the time to learn a lot more about the whole WPF concept, because I already see that I have only scratched the surface so far.

Comment: Would you like me to share my answer on your other question? for other use?

Answer (score 1):

well I'm thinking probably the best thing to do would be to create another form and design it in the way u want then when u click the print button print that form... don't forget to databind the objects.... easiest method would be to use datastore.

Comment: Well, I know this would work, but I wanted to avoid a duplication, because it makes maintenance harder.However, possibly I can create a kind of template, from which then two different forms can be generated ... I need some time to go through this more thorougly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation: As a temporary solution, I found a way to replace a control in some panel at runtime like this:

```
this.somepanel.Children.Remove(this.sometextbox); 
TextBlock n=new TextBlock(); 
n.Text = "...";
n.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
this.somepanel.Children.Add(n);
```

This is a solution that works; however, I'm quite sure that there are better solutions, which make better use of the whole WPF concept.

However, for the time being, I do it like this for a 1st version. For a 2nd version, I will go more in depth of WPF, and possibly post an additional answer or article.